# Show field based on selected option - Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to show a field based on a selected option "usa". I am working on creating dynamic reactive form fields but I can't show and hide a field based on selected option. This what I tried.

AppComponent html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div
    formArrayName="formArray"
    *ngFor="let formArr of myForm.get('formArray').controls; let i = index"
  >
    <div [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <label for="name"> First name Name:</label>
          <input  formControlName="firstName"  placeholder="First name">
<label for="name">Last name :</label>
          <input   formControlName="lastName"  placeholder="Last name">

          <select formControlName="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectCountry" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
      <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c"> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
        <div *ngIf="showPostcode">
              <label for="name"> Post Code </label>
          <input  formControlName="postcode"  placeholder="Post code"> // this field what i'm trying to show or hide
          </div>

      </div>
      <button (click)="addForm()">Add new form</button>
      <br /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button (click)="SubmitApp()">Button</button>

  <br />
  <br />
  <div style="border-style: dashed;"></div>
</form>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
showPostcode = false;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      formArray: this.fb.array([this.createItem()]),
    });
  }

createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: [""],
      lastName: [""],
      countries: [""],
      postcode:[""]
    });
  }


  addForm() {
    this.formArray = this.myForm.get("arr") as FormArray;
    this.formArray.push(this.createItem());
  }


onChange(country)
{
if(country.name == "usa")
this.showPostcode = true;
}

}
```

P.s : Remember that may i create multiple fields using "add new field button". Need help please.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer. Use:

```
<div *ngIf="formArr.get('countries').value=='usa'">
```

But let me try to explain something:

First, David NOT use [ngModel] nor (ngModelChange) in the input you use formControlName. If you want to acces the value of a formControl use the methods to get the value of a formControl.

Well, how access to this value? in general we use the way

```
nameMyform.get('nameOfControl').value
```

When you use a Form array you can do something like

```
myForm.get('formArray').at(i).get('countries')
```

Well, really you can not do this -if you make a ng build --prod give you an error- When we use a FormArray use a getter to get the value of array

```
get myArray()
{
    return this.myForm.get('formArray') as FormArray
}
```

You iterate over

```
<div formArrayName="formArray">
    <div *ngFor="let formArr of myArray.controls; let i = index"
         [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"  >
         ....
    </div>
<div >
```

(see that the "div" I iterate is the "div" of the formGroup not the div of the formArrayName=

And use

```
myArray.at(i).get('countries').value
```

But you can use the iterating variable, yes, your variable **formArr** of the "let formArr of ..." is a formGroup, so you can use

```
formArr.get('countries').value
```

Well, not so quick, you use `<option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c">`. That's mean that the value of your myArray.at(i).get('countries') are the "whole" object "c" -I supouse you want to say `[ngValue]="c.name"` or "c.ISOName" or some similar.